# Three.js - extrude SVG with r69 or r73

Tags: javascript, svg, three.js

I'm a bit confused by conflicting methods on how to extrude an SVG in Three.js.

One tutorial with r69 is here: http://www.smartjava.org/ltjs/chapter-06/05-extrude-svg.html . It uses a library called d3-threeD.js, but when I replace the svg details (everything after the "d=") then it does not work.

There are other examples that I see that use these libraries:

```
<script src="http://threejs.org/examples/js/renderers/SVGRenderer.js"></script>
<script src="http://threejs.org/examples/js/renderers/Projector.js"></script>
<script src="http://threejs.org/examples/js/loaders/SVGLoader.js"></script>
```

but (i think) they dont allow for extrusion because they display the SVG as an image.

My svg is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
 viewBox="0 0 512 512" enable-background="new 0 0 512 512" xml:space="preserve"> <path fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M498.7,373.2c-0.1-43-35.1-78.7-78.1-78.7c-0.3,0-0.6,0-0.9,0
C414,262,382,209,313,210c-71.9,1-112,48-121.1,88.4c-17.2-24-50.2-33.2-81.9-32.4c-86,2-93.6,107.2-93.6,107.2H498.7z"/> </svg>
```

Comment: it would be easier if you showed us what `d=` you use so we can figure what the problem is with the example.

Comment: sorry about that! Here is the full SVG code:
<svg version="1.0" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
  viewBox="0 0 500 300" enable-background="new 0 0 500 300" xml:space="preserve">
<path fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M481.7,248.5c-0.1-42-33.9-76.8-76-76.8c-0.3,0-0.6,0-0.9,0
 C397.7,130.2,377.8,53,294.7,53c-70.2,0-102.4,51.8-112.6,98.6c-16.8-23.4-44.1-38.5-75.1-38.5c-97.7,0-96,135.4-96,135.4H481.7z"/>
</svg>

Comment: if you take your path and you plug it in here: http://jsfiddle.net/drewnoakes/GNm8W/ there is no output. so the path is probably the problem